# What is meant by the discriminant locus of a fibration?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, differential-geometry

If we have a fibration $f: X \to B$ (allowing singular fibers) of a differentiable manifold $X$, precisely what is meant by "the discriminant locus of $f$ " $\Delta \subset B$ and how do we define it? Can it be realized as the zero locus of a section?

Comment: The the set of points with singular fiber, probably.